# Strange Ruby behavior with || and &&

Tags: ruby, logical-operators, puts

```
def a
  puts 'a'
end

def b
  puts 'b'
end

p a || b #=> prints both 'a' and 'b' although it would only print a

p a && b #=> prints only a
```

What's going on? I'm using 1.9.3

Edit: I forgot puts returns nil, now it makes sense, thanks to the first answer :)

Comment: Nothing strange `:puts` method returns `nil`

Comment: Ups, I forgot this, now it all makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing strange, since `:puts` method returns `nil`, the second argument of `&&` operator didn't evaluated. However, in first case you've get the both call to `:a`, and then to `:b`, because `:a` method returned `nil`.